# How to show compass on Google Street View for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view

I am using GMSPanoramaView provided by the Maps SDK for iOS. I couldn't find any options regarding on the compass. Is there anyway to show a compass on the Street View like on the web version?

Answer (score 0):

If the navigation bar is visible, the compass button is behind it. To make it appear you need to add padding to the top side of the map view.

**Swift:**

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
mapView.padding = mapInsets
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't work out. Guess GMSPanoramaView doesn't have a compass.